# Export all fields in table to Excel and suppress blank columns

Tags: excel

Somewhat of a newbie...
I'm trying to find a way to easily export all fields (~50) in my table to Excel. Even if I need to drag each individual field into the design, I can't fit all ~50 fields.
Additionally, I'd love to be able to suppress any blank columns, if possible.
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a little more detail. Export from where?

Comment: Sorry...from SAP Crystal. I'm using Version 14.2.5.2618, if that helps.